# PHP cURL HTTP PUT

Tags: php, rest, curl, put, http-put

I am trying to create a HTTP PUT request with cURL and I can't make it work. I've read many tutorials but none of them actually worked. Here's my current code:

```
$filedata = array('metadata' => $rdfxml);
$ch = curl_init($url);
$header = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='123456f'";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($filedata));
$returned = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_error($ch))
{
    print curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    print 'ret: ' .$returned;
}
```

I've also tried using PHP PEAR but got the same result. The problem is that the repository says that no metadata has been set. I really need help! Thanks!

Answer (score 190):

Just been doing that myself today... here is code I have working for me...

```
$data = array("a" => $a);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$response) 
{
    return false;
}
```

src: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2009/putting-data-fields-with-php-curl

Comment: Note that I tried using `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);` as well as this code and it didn't work, so `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);` must be removed.

Comment: How do you read the PUT data? I've tried everything but no luck. POST, GET or REQUEST do not work.

Comment: @andrebruton  I would try `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Answer (score 27):

Using Postman for Chrome, selecting CODE you get this...  And works

```html
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://blablabla.com/comorl",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n  \"customer\" : \"con\",\n  \"customerID\" : \"5108\",\n  \"customerEmail\" : \"jordi@correo.es\",\n  \"Phone\" : \"34600000000\",\n  \"Active\" : false,\n  \"AudioWelcome\" : \"https://audio.com/welcome-defecto-es.mp3\"\n\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
    "x-api-key: whateveriyouneedinyourheader"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}

?>
```

Comment: What a great tip! I didn't know Postman could generate code!

Answer (score 7):

In a POST method, you can put an array. However, in a PUT method, you should use `http_build_query` to build the params like this:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $postArr ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed 2 standard.

The error is in `$header = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='123456f'";`

The function `http_build_query($filedata)` is only for "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", or none.