# convert the curl command curl -X PUT -d

Tags: php, json, curl

its simple question
can anybody convert this curl command to equivalent php code

```
   curl -X PUT -d '{
  "alanisawesome": {
    "name": "Alan Turing",
    "birthday": "June 23, 1912"
  }
}' 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/fireblog/users.json'
```

i am new to curl, please explain where '-X' option and '-d' options are specified

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cURL HTTP PUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043525/php-curl-http-put)

Answer (score 2):

For the options, take a look to the documentation : 
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

> **-d, --data < data > :**
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
>   in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
>   form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the
>   data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
>
> **-X, --request < command > :**
>
> (HTTP) Specifies a custom request method to use when communicating
>   with the HTTP server. The specified request method will be used
>   instead of the method otherwise used (which defaults to GET). Read the
>   HTTP 1.1 specification for details and explanations. Common additional
>   HTTP requests include PUT and DELETE, but related technologies like
>   WebDAV offers PROPFIND, COPY, MOVE and more.
>
> Normally you don't need this option. All sorts of GET, HEAD, POST and
>   PUT requests are rather invoked by using dedicated command line
>   options.