# Sending a PUT request from PHP to Hubspot

Tags: php, rest, api, curl, put

This problem is really bugging me, i'm a hobby programmer who right now is trying to follow the simple instructions of Hubspots CRM API documentation.

I've managed to retrieve and POST information from and to Hubspot using cURL/PHP, but now i'm facing an update(PUT) and i can figure it out.

I'm trying to associate a "Deal" with a "Contact" inside the CRM, it seems to be so easy, just fire away a url? :)

The documentation on the API says:

> Note: You only need to use this endpoint when updating existing deal records. If you are creating new deals, you can make these associations when creating the record by including the associations data as documented on the create deal page."

src: https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/deals/associate_deal

Do i understand correctly, i tried to use this URL in my browser and expected an update to happen?

https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/DEALID/associations/CONTACT?id=CONTACTID&hapikey=MyKey

The response i got in the browsers console was: 405 (Method not allowed).

I tried to fire the url though cURL aswell, but got lost right away because i dont really have any data to send in "CURLOPT" parameters, the data should, if i understand correctly be inside the endpoint url.

If you have any idea of what this hobby programmer doesnt understand, please reply :)

Kind regards,

Simon

Comment: You know, hubspot has a forum https://integrate.hubspot.com/

Probably, it would be easier to get help from the guys that made the tool...

Comment: Thanks, i went through their forum without any results. But yeah, i should probably post there to. Thanks Leonardo

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to make a PUT request from your browser.

Comment: You should be able to do it with cURL, just passing the data in the URL like you said.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043525/php-curl-http-put

Comment: You can use Postman aswell. Its a chrome extension which is to test API requests.

Comment: It worked. Strange :) I inserted some data into the cURL that i never used, now it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cURL HTTP PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043525/php-curl-http-put)